# Some questions on a function

Tags: python

```
def get_party_stats(families, table_size=6):

    """To calculate the number of attendees and tables needed.

    Args:
        families(list): a list of members.
        table_size(int): table size of 6.

    Returns:
        mixed: people count & table count.

    Examples:

        >>> get_party_stats([['Jan'], ['Jen', 'Jess'], ['Jem', 'Jack',
        'Janis']])
        '(6, 3)'
    """
    table_num = 0
    people_num = 0

    for people in families:
        table_num += -(-len(people)//table_size)
        people_num += len(people)
    return people_num, table_num
```

How do you get `people_num` to return `6`, if `len(people)` is only `3`. For `table_num`, having the negative signs in `-(-len(people)//table_size)`, what does that achieve? Is there another way to count for number of attendees and tables, using some simple examples? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you sum over the sizes of each family `people_num` will come out as  `len(['Jan']) + len(['Jen', 'Jess']) + len(['Jem', 'Jack', 'Janis']) = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6`.

The `-(-len(people)//table_size)` term is a bit sneaky but you will realize what it does by noting that `a // b == floor(a / b)`. Integer division `c = a // b` is defined such that `c` is the biggest integer number such that `c <= a / b` (note that `/` means float-division here). This makes `abs(a) // abs(b) !=  abs(a // b)` when `a / b < 0` but is exactly what you want when calculating the number of tables necessary in your function.

The following results may illustrate that:

```
 -1 // 6 == -1           1 // 6 == 0
 -2 // 6 == -1           2 // 6 == 0 
      ...                    ...
 -6 // 6 == -1           6 // 6 == 1 
 -7 // 6 == -2           7 // 6 == 1 
 -8 // 6 == -2           8 // 6 == 1
      ...                    ...
-12 // 6 == -2          12 // 6 == 2 
-13 // 6 == -3          13 // 6 == 2
```

Another (maybe less elegant) way of calculating the number of tables necessary given `people` would be `1 + (len(people) - 1) // table_size`.

Finally, the whole function could be made a lot shorter using list-comprehensions:

```
def get_party_stats(families, table_size=6):
    return (sum([len(f) for f in families]),
            sum([-(-len(f) // table_size) for f in families]))
```

Comment: @ siwica I get the first part about the len(), second part on the floor division with negative numbers seems a little confusing. And the last part using list comprehension, it's pretty neat, something to take away from. Thank you.

Comment: @ siwica floor divisions with negative numbers are mostly used when ?